# Deleting an Application's AppRole in Azure Active Directory

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api, azure-ad-powershell-v2

Removing an AppRole from an Application’s manifest produces a 400 Bad Request with the error

> Property value cannot be deleted unless it is disabled first.

When I set the isEnabled property to false and then hit save, I get a successful saven with a 200 OK looking at the browsers developer tools:

[image: Before]

After reloading the Edit manifest screen the `isEnabled` property is still `true` and if you look at the PUT response in the browsers developer tools, it's coming back as `true` there too.

[image: After]

How can I remove an appRole without having to delete and recreate the entire application?

## Update

I've raised the following [bug](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/19002091-bug-unable-to-delete-an-application-s-approle).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Until this gets fixed, there two options to work around this issue:

1. Using Azure AD PowerShell, you can disable and then remove the app role. Here's a sample script that would achieve this:

   ```ps
   $appId = "83d7d56d-6e64-4791-b8e8-9a8da8dd957e"
   $appRoleValue = "app-role-value" # i.e. the scope

   Connect-AzureAD

   # Disable the AppRole
   $app = Get-AzureADApplication -Filter "appId eq '$appId'"
   ($app.AppRoles | Where-Object { $_.Value -eq $appRoleValue }).IsEnabled = $false
   Set-AzureADApplication -ObjectId $app.ObjectId -AppRoles $app.AppRoles

   # Remove the AppRole
   $toRemove = $app.AppRoles | Where-Object { $_.Value -eq $appRoleValue }
   $app.AppRoles.Remove($toRemove) | Out-Null
   Set-AzureADApplication -ObjectId $app.ObjectId -AppRoles $app.AppRoles
   ```
2. An alternative option is to user the Azure AD Graph Explorer and issue two `PATCH` requests on the Application object. The first `PATCH` request should set the app role's `isEnabled` attribute to `false`. The second `PATCH` request can then remove the app role (i.e. include all existing app roles except the disabled one).

Answer (score 19):

This bug is fixed now.  All you have to do is set `isEnabled` to **false** and save.  Then you can delete the role and save again.  A Work-around is not necessary.

Comment: Tried this simple solution also, out of curiosity, and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 8):

To Delete the Application Role:

1. Go to application Manifest.
2. App Role you want to delete, change the value of `isEnabled` to false.
3. Save the manifest.
4. Delete the that approle.
5. Again save it.

Comment: Note: This is only true post the Bug Fix mentioned by @JohnHenckel

Answer (score 3):

It seems a bug in new portal . The save operation doesn't save `isEnabled` to false on server side . Any feedback , you could post to [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory) .

Currently , you could use Azure AD classic portal to modify the app roles in manifest(download the manifest and then upload manifest that changed) . Delete app roles in classic portal works fine in my environment . Please let me know if it helps.

Comment: I've raised the following [bug](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/19002091-bug-unable-to-delete-an-application-s-approle).

Comment: Annoyingly, I don't have access to the classic Azure portal. Is there some other way I can work around this bug? Is there any planned fix for it?

Comment: I will check whether graph api works, but currently seems only classic portal could make it work without api/powershell .

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same error message `Property value cannot be deleted unless it is disabled first.` because I have created the scope on one page page and tried to add it manually in the Manifest on another web page. Little I knew the manifest was updated automatically and I just needed to reload it.

Answer (score 0):

*You cannot delete the assigned roles which are enabled, you first have to set the flag isEnable to false and save the manifest for the roles which you want to delete like this -->`"isEnabled": false` in the manifest and now try to delete the whole appRoles part.*

This is a two-step process but works.

Answer (score 0):

- Navigate to your Application
- Go to App Roles

  [image: Snip]
- Click on the app role display name
- Untick the checkbox to disable the Role

  [image: Snip]
- Go back to the manifest and make changes to the `appRoles` section as you need

  [image: Snip]
- Save and it should be updated

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: @Chris thanks . I'll defo read that...